# Join Tables Based on Correlated Subquery, SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I need to join two tables that are described below:

```
Table1:
ID  Date       Info1
1   1/29/2011     i10
1   1/30/2011     i11


Table2:
ID  Date       Info2
1    1/31/2011   i2
```

I would like to left join the records in Table 2 identified by ID, Month, Year to that in Table 1 identified by the same ID, Month, Year but use the last available record date as the joining record.  So for example, in the data above I would join the record in Table 2 to the second record in Table 1 because they match in ID, Month, Year and record 2 of Table 1 has the greatest available day for that (ID, Month, Year) combination.  The correct result is:

> ID   Date  Info1   Info2
>
> 1   1/30/2011     i11   i2

The SQL code I am coming up with so far is pretty convoluted.  Please suggest something. I am using MySQL.

Comment: why don't you post what you've got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [I want to] ...use the last available record date as the joining record

Solve that first, with a derived table. Assuming that `ID, Date` is unique, then you can easily group by ID and take the MAX date.

```
SELECT
   T1.*,
   T2.*
FROM Table1 as T1
JOIN (
   SELECT 
      ID, MAX(Date) as Date
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY 
      ID
) as Last ON
   T1.ID = Last.ID
   AND T1.Date = Last.Date
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 as T2 ON
   T1.ID = Last.ID
   AND MONTH(T1.Date) = MONTH(T2.Date)
   AND YEAR(T1.Date) = YEAR(T2.Date)
```